# How to make an "eachable" (being able to call .each) in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, each

I know that Collections, Arrays, Maps etc. can be traversed with `.each` in Groovy.

How can I make a class respond to `.each`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure))

> Custom types may utilize this method by simply providing an "iterator()" method.